# Repeating Value Unity

Tags: math, unity-game-engine, unityscript

It should give me a random value missing. It either gives me -.75 or .75 as missing however instead of any value from the list of outputs.

```
var Rando : float;
function Start () {
   Amount = Random.Range(8,9);
    while (Amount > 0) { //CREATING THE BLOCKS
        Rando = (-27.0f + (Random.Range(0,9) * 6.0f)) / 4.0f;
        while (AmountArray.Contains(Rando)) {
            Rando = (-27.0f + (Random.Range(0,9) * 6.0f)) / 4.0f;
        }
        AmountArray.Add (Rando);
        Amount--;
    }
    AmountArray.Clear();
}
```

Comment: Could you clarify your question a bit.  "It should give me a random value missing" is unclear.  Adding your expected output and actual output would also help.

Comment: Do note that [Random.Range](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Random.Range.html) for integer values **excludes** the last value. So Amount will always be equal to 8.